# how to set coordinates, id and offset for a Kinetic Image

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I have a kinetic image in my drawImage function:

```
var kImage = new Kinetic.Image({
          id: 'myImage',
          x: 200,
          y: 50,
          image: imageObj,
          width: 106,
          height: 118
        });
```

Now, I need to put kImage as a global varible, and set x, y, id... in the drawImage function.

I did:

```
function drawImage() {
    kImage.setX= ...
    kImage.setId=... 
}
```

but it seems that the kImage that I get in the end is "empty". 
kImage.getX() returns 0 for example and it is the same thing for the other fields.

Could you tell me what's wrong here please?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you make a fiddle for your problem, it will be much easier seeing the code rather than guessing which variable is define and what is their scope.

Answer (score 2):

**Set Coordinates**

`kImage.setX(x)` and `kImage.setY(y)`

or

`kImage.setPosition(x, y)`

**Set ID**

`kImage.setId(id)`

**Set Offset**

`kImage.setOffsetX(x)` and `kImage.setOffsetY(y)`

or

`kImage.setOffset(x, y)`

**Sources**

[Kinetic.Shape#setX](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setX)

[Kinetic.Shape#setY](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setY)

[Kinetic.Shape#setPosition](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setPosition)

[Kinetic.Shape#setId](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setId)

[Kinetic.Shape#setOffsetX](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setOffsetX)

[Kinetic.Shape#setOffsetY](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setOffsetY)

[Kinetic.Shape#setOffset](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Shape.html#setOffset)

Comment: I've done this. but when I do kImage.getId() in another function, I get 0

Comment: Is that a scoping issue? Does your other function have access to kImage? You might have to move where you declare `var kImage` at first.

Comment: kImage is a global variable

Comment: The scoping issue might be about how you declare and use `var id` rather than `var kImage`

Comment: @Ani  thank you for your answer. I just edited my question. I don't declare id.

Comment: @projeqht thank you for your answer. I just edited my code. You can see that for id for example, I'm setting a 'myImage' and I got "undefined" when trying to access it

Comment: You don't call the function by running `kImage.setX=` and `kImage.setId=`. You call the function by running `kImage.setX(x)` and `kImage.setId(id)`